# How can I add an attribute of type NG to a Div

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component where I use #gmap, except that the div where it is located I have it saved in a json, therefore it does not recognize me #gmap. If I insert it directly in the html file of the component, it recognizes me without problems.

I have tried adding a new attribute to the div from code, example: document.getElementById ('myDiv'). SetAttribute ('# gmap', '');
but I did not succeed.

In my Json I have a property with this text

```html
<div #gmap style = "width: 100%; height: 400px"> </ div>
```

But when compiling, I am geting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at ...
```

Since the way to add a #NG from a string is not correct, does someone know how to add it from code?
Example:

```
myDiv.setNg ('# gmap')
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```have it saved in a json```?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using google translate, I do not speak English.

I mean I have some html elements stored in a json, for example:
"htmls": {
"value1": "</ h6> <small class = 'text-muted p-t-30 db'> telephone </ small> <h6>",
"value2": "<div> html code </ div>",
...
...
}
This in order not to overload my html component, since I handle several cases, and when a certain case is fulfilled add html content.
example:
document.getElementById('divExample')..innerHTML += const.htmls.divCodeExample;

Comment: I just want to know if you can add an #Ng property using code, in this case #gmap, something like:
document.getElementById ('element'). addNgPropert ('# gmap').
And that the result is of:
<div id = "element"> </ div>
to
<div id = "element" #gmap> </ div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pose an interesting question. My understanding of template variables (the #gmap or #something that you plug into an element) are that they are an Angular creation and so can't be programatically edited through JavaScript API's (and I know of no Angular methods to do so either). They are also static variables, so they can't be re-named.

A work-around I can think of if you're going down this route is to switch to using plane JavaScript id's. So instead of #gmap, you would just use id="gmap".

Wish I could be more helpful. Good luck!

Comment: I understand, I gave up, my solution (the one I did not want to implement) was to create my forms in my component, and by code to eliminate or hide those that I would not occupy in X cases.
Thanks